# Python SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Tags: python

I have just upgraded my python from 2 to 3 and start getting following error. I have checked indent and spaces also but no luck

CODE

```
def _download_track(self, song_url, track_name, dir_name,metadata):
    if '.mp4' in song_url:
        track_name = track_name + '.m4a'
    else:
        track_name = track_name + '.mp3'        
    file_path = dir_name.replace(".","_") + '/' + track_name
    print(('Downloading to', file_path))
if os.path.isfile(file_path):
       return
    #print metadata
    #response = self._get_url_contents(song_url)
    #with open(file_path,'wb') as f:
    #f.write(response.content)
r = requests.get(song_url, stream=True, verify=False)
with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
        if chunk:
            f.write(chunk)
            f.flush()
    if '.m4a' in track_name:
        self._update_metadata_mp4(file_path,metadata)
    else :
        self._update_metadata_mp3(file_path,metadata)
```

ERROR

```
  File "a.py", line 60
    return
    ^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

Comment: It's likely that you meant to indent the `if os.path.isfile(file_path):` line another time.

Comment: i think its because `intentation` error check this line `if os.path.isfile(file_path):
       return` should come inside `def`

Comment: indentation matters in python. Voting to close as off-topic, this is basically a typo/syntax error that you can solve with proper indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code of the entire function has to be indented:

```
def _download_track(self, song_url, track_name, dir_name,metadata):
    if '.mp4' in song_url:
        track_name = track_name + '.m4a'
    else:
        track_name = track_name + '.mp3'        
    file_path = dir_name.replace(".","_") + '/' + track_name
    print(('Downloading to', file_path))
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        return
        #print metadata
        #response = self._get_url_contents(song_url)
        #with open(file_path,'wb') as f:
        #f.write(response.content)
    r = requests.get(song_url, stream=True, verify=False)
    with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)
                f.flush()
        if '.m4a' in track_name:
            self._update_metadata_mp4(file_path,metadata)
        else :
            self._update_metadata_mp3(file_path,metadata)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your line:

```
if os.path.isfile(file_path):
```

is not indented so it is not within the function. 'return' is after that so it is not in the function either.